# Get error when use internet but don't get error on server

Tags: 2010

I use this coe for  save image in word document.

```
 System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
 request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 request.PreAuthenticate = true;
 request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

 System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SignAddress);
 myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
 myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

 WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();

                           //Get a stream from the webresponse
  Stream stream = myResp.GetResponseStream();
```

when run this in server, it is work .

but when i run this with internet(ip) i get error :

**Trying to use SPWEb object that has been clesed or disposed and is no longer valid.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace this code for get stream. it is work for me :)

```
   SPFile Signfile = web.GetFile(SignAddress);
    if (Signfile.Exists)
     {
         stream = Signfile.OpenBinaryStream();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to try:

1. Make sure that if you use the IP it is also added into the AAM
2. When using DEfaultCredentials the machine from which you are trying must be added to the same Domain, otherwise it will never work (e.g. Extranet/Intranet scenarios)
3. Always check the SPContext is NOT Null (if you just take the example in a Console like this it will never work) - you would need to rely on the Managed Client Object Model or otherwise SPCOntext has no value (example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Using_the_Managed_Client_Object_Model). However if this is built into a Application Page or Web Part it should be ok.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I check all, but don't work!

Comment: instead of using DefaultCredentials try passing the same credentials manually of the user you are logged on with while testing from your server.